# Do the Steam versions of the LucasArts Adventure Games work with ScummVM?

Tags: scummvm, the-dig, loom, indiana-jones-fate-of-atlantis, indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade

There are several LucasArts adventure games that are available for sale on Steam.

- Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade
- Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis
- Loom
- The Dig

Do any of these Steam versions work with ScummVM?

Comment: I'm self-answering this question because I found that a lot of information available online was out of date, and want to save others the half hour search I went through to get the latest answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, with ScummVM 1.7.0 and later

The ScummVM 1.7.0 [release notes](https://www.scummvm.org/frs/scummvm/1.7.0/ReleaseNotes) say the following:

> Added support for the Steam versions of Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade, Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis, Loom and The Dig. Both the Windows and the Macintosh versions are supported.

For example, if you want to run *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*, you click the "Add Game" button in ScummVM and point to the following locations:

- **Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade/The Last Crusade.app`
- **Windows:** `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade`

Other games can be found in similar locations.

### And it works on Linux and other platforms!

See "[Can I use Linux to download games that will be played on Windows?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/296162/47878)" for several methods on how to download the Windows/Mac binaries on Linux via Steam, which can then be loaded into ScummVM.